# LAMP virtual machine as a real server

Tags: server, lamp

Dummy question here, I'm pretty new to some stuff like setting up server configuration, etc.
So my question is, can i set up a LAMP virtual machine and use it as a real server?
I mean can the web pages in the www directory be accessed from another computer like if it was a regular server??

Comment: yes, as far as just running it in a virtual machine?  That is the direction most servers seem to be going (in my neck of the woods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Answer: Yes

The VM has to have its network interface routed to the host machine to be accessible from host's network.

How this is done depends on the OS and VM software.

Comment: Just as I thought :) Thanks for the quick response. I'll accept your answer and sart researching on my own.